# My little C++ library for comfortable programming

Tags: c++, beginner, windows, library

I've tried to make a little library in C++, to gather all useful and necessary functions. I wrote the code(in one file, to make it more portable). Unfortunately, it works on Windows only.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef NEWCPP
    #define NEWCPP

    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <sstream>

    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stdexcept>

    #include <cstdarg>

    using namespace std;

    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    
    namespace newcppPrivate {
        void Init() {
            srand(time(0));
        }
        const int fileInitializeStartTime = (int)time(0);
        #define STARTTIME fileInitializeStartTime
        #define PRESSTIMESLEEP 10
    }
    using namespace newcppPrivate;
    
    namespace COLORS {
        #define CLASSIC (-1) //WORD

        #define INVISIBLEBLACK 0

        #define BLUE 1
        #define GREEN 2
        #define LIGHTBLUE 3
        #define RED 4
        #define PURPLE 5
        #define YELLOW 6
        #define WHITE 7
        #define GREY 8
        #define LIGHTBLUE 9
        #define LIGHTGREEN 10
        #define CYAN 11
        #define LIGHTRED 12
        #define PINK 13
        #define LIGHTYELLOW 14
        #define WHITE2 15
    }
    using namespace COLORS;

    #ifdef _WIN32
        #include <io.h>
        #define access _access_s
    #else
        #include <unistd.h>
    #endif

    //Gives true if folder exist.
    bool DirExist(const string& path) {
        struct stat buffer;
        return (stat(path.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); //return PathFileExists(path.c_str());
    }

    //Returns string converted to wstring.
    wstring StringToWString(const string s) {
        std::wstring wsTmp(s.begin(), s.end());
        return wsTmp;
    }

    LPCWSTR s2ws(const std::string& s) {
        int len;
        int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
        len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
        wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
        std::wstring r(buf);
        delete[] buf;
        //return r;

        std::wstring stemp = s2ws(s);
        return stemp.c_str();
    }

    //Returns string converted to LPSTR
    LPSTR StrToLPSTR(string s) {
        return const_cast <char*> (s.c_str());
    }

    //Returns true if given char is number
    bool isCharNumber(char c) {
        return isdigit(c);
    }

    //Deleting all given chars from string and returns it.
    string DeleteAllChars(string s, char c) {
        s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), c), s.end());
        return s;
    }

    //Deleting chars from first parameter that are in second.
    string DeleteAllChars(string s, string chars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++)
            s = DeleteAllChars(s, chars[i]);
        return s;
    }

    //Replacing string in text to another string.
    //Usage:
    //ReplaceAll(string("The main string"), string(" "), string("-"))
    //Returns:
    //"The-main-string"
    string ReplaceAll(std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
        size_t start_pos = 0;
        while ((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
            str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
            start_pos += to.length(); // Handles case where 'to' is a substring of 'from'
        }
        return str;
    }

    //Returns a chracter table length.
    int CharacterTableLength() {
        //return int(char(0) - 1);
        char a = 'a' + 1;
        int counter = 1;
        while (a != 'a') {
            a++;
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }

    //Returns string to uppercase
    string UpperString(string s) {
        transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
        return s;
    }

    template <typename T>
    string NumberToString(T pNumber) {
        ostringstream oOStrStream;
        oOStrStream << pNumber;
        return oOStrStream.str();
    }

    //Returns true if element is part of array.
    template <class element, class container>
    bool PartOfArray(element elem, container array, int arraySize=0) {
        if (!arraySize) arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            if (elem == array[i])
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    //Returns true if __access_s function returns 0 (~file exists)
    bool FileExists(const std::string& Filename) {
        return _access(Filename.c_str(), 0) == 0;
    }

    //Changing console text color. For changing it back, ChangeColor(COLORS::CLASSIC) or SetDefaultColor
    void ChangeColor(int color = CLASSIC) {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, color);
    }

    //Setting standart color
    void SetDefaultColor() {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, CLASSIC);
    }

    //Writes each symbol in string with function Sleep
    void Write(string s, int maxTime=100) {
        if (maxTime <= 0) maxTime = 1; //Previous version was without it
        //srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            cout << s[i];
            Sleep(rand() % maxTime); //WARNING: Slowing down.
        }
    }

    //Writes string in setted color with Sleep.
    void Print(string s, int color=CLASSIC, int maxT=1, int colorAfter=CLASSIC) {
        ChangeColor(color); //WARNING: Calling SetConsoleTextAttribute insead should speed up.
        Write(s, maxT); //Slows down output.
        ChangeColor(colorAfter);
    }

    //Simulating user press
    void Press(BYTE key, int sleepTime=PRESSTIMESLEEP) {
        keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(sleepTime);
        keybd_event(key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }

    //Simulating 2 presses
    void DoublePress(BYTE key, BYTE key2, int sleepTime=PRESSTIMESLEEP) {
        keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(key2, 0, 0, 0);

        Sleep(sleepTime);

        keybd_event(key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        keybd_event(key2, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }

    template<class T>
    T Random(T min = 0, T max = 10000) {
        max -= min;
        T res = rand() % (max+1);
        return res + min;
    }

    //Class for bruteforcing.
    class BruteForce {
    private:
        const char pzc = 1;
        const char pnc = 0;
    public:
        string res = ""; //Bruteforce guess

        //Give next string guess
        string GiveNextGuess() {
            PlusPlus();
            return res;
        }

        string CurrentGuess() {
            return res;
        }

        //Setting start length of brute-force string. Can be given as normal(parameter 2 but s is maybe ['', ''])
        void SetStartLength(int l) {
            if (l <= 0) throw std::invalid_argument("Received incorrect value.");
            res.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
                res += pzc;
        }

        void PlusPlus() {
            int a = 0;
            while (true) {
                if (a > res.length()) {
                    res += pzc;
                    break;
                }
                else if (res[a] == pnc) {
                    res[a] = pzc;
                    a++;
                }
                else {
                    res[a]++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    namespace sortfunctions {
        template<class T>
        vector<T> GnomeSort(vector<T> arr, bool (*compare)(T, T)) {
            const int s = arr.size();
            for (int i = 1; i < s; i++) {
                if (compare(arr[i], arr[i - 1])) {
                    T helper = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
                    arr[i - 1] = helper;
                    if (i != 1) i -= 2;
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }

        template<class T>
        vector<T> BubbleSort(vector<T> arr, bool (*compare)(T, T)) {
            const int s = arr.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                for (int k = i + 1; k < s; k++) {
                    if (compare(arr[i], arr[k])) {
                        T helper = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[k];
                        arr[k] = helper;
                    }
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }

    //Returns junk. Should return last value somewhere in program used. Needs to give any string.
    template<class T>
    const int GetJunk(T r = 10) { if (r != r) return 0; }
#endif
```

### Questions:

1. Can it be done in other way? For example, I can write code in multiple files, but then compile into one .lib file? If so, how to install it then?
2. Any code review suggestions?

---

#### Some notes

`CharacterTableLength` - is function that should return number of all symbols installed on the computer. For example, if on computer installed 3 languages, this function should return number of special and 3 languages symbols.

I specially wrote variable names without '_'. I really dont like this style, I use Camel case instead.

Comment: `GnomeSort` and `BubbleSort` are useful and necessary on Windows?  Glad I never had to write anything for that platform!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## General Observations

> Can it be done in other way? For example, I can write code in multiple files, but then compile into one .lib file? If so, how to install it then?

Generally it is best to put functions into C++ source files and have header files that provide the interfaces (function prototypes and constants). A library can contain multiple source files, how to do this depends on whether it is a static library or a dynamic library. Putting functions into a header file means that if a function is modified everything needs to be recompiled. If only the function prototype is in the header file then generally to fix a bug means recompiling one file and re-linking the program or library.

Please compile using all the warning messages you can. It helps find possible bugs. I compile with more warning messages than you apparently do and this is what I see when I compile:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: myLittleLib, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>myLittleLib.cpp
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(28,19): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion     from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(49,1): warning C4005: 'LIGHTBLUE': macro redefinition
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(43): message : see previous definition of 'LIGHTBLUE'
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(110,23): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(186,23): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(253,19): warning C4018: '>': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\myLittleLib\myCppLib.h(90): warning C4717: 's2ws': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
1>myLittleLib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\PaulC\Documents\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\myLittleLib\Debug\myLittleLib.exe
1>Done building project "myLittleLib.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Professional

## Include Guards

I'm assuming this library is a header file because of the include guards. In C++ use either `#pragma once` or `#ifndef` but you don't need both. I prefer `#ifndef` because it may be more portable, not all C++ compilers support `#pragma once` but it is widely supported.

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

This code is abusing `using namespace ANYNAMESPACE;`

Never put `using namespace std;` in a header file.

## Use Enum Types

Rather than using a lot of `#defines` which are frowned on in C++, there are 2 ways to create constants. One is to use [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), the other is using an [enum type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum). When more than 2 or 3 constants are being defined an enum is a better way to do this. The link I provided shows an example of a color enum, however, this is what the current code could look like:

```
    enum MyCOLORS
    {
        BLUE,
        GREEN,
        RED,
        PURPLE,
        YELLOW,
        WHITE,
        GREY,
        LIGHTBLUE,
        LIGHTGREEN,
        CYAN,
        LIGHTRED,
        PINK,
        LIGHTYELLOW,
        WHITE2
    };
```

Please note that in the code under review LIGHTBLUE is defined twice which should be reported by the compiler.

## Type Mismatch in `for` Loops

Container classes such as `std::string` and `wstring` return the type `size_t` from the `length` or `size` member. The type `size_t` varies from compiler to compiler but it is always `unsigned`, in many cases it is either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`. One of the possible reasons for this is to prevent negative indexes when using the variable as an index into the container.

```
string DeleteAllChars(string s, string chars) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++)
        s = DeleteAllChars(s, chars[i]);
    return s;
}
```

Negative indexes can have bad side affects and cause exceptions.

## Reinventing the Wheel

There is no good reason for this function

```
bool isCharNumber(char c) {
    return isdigit(c);
}
```

The function `isdigit()` is well known and well documented, why replace it with an unknown, undocumented function?

Comment: Also, raw `char` to a character-function? The UB.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how your file is meant to be used.  It appears to be set up like a header file, but nothing in it is `inline` so it can only appear in one translation unit.  From your comments, I suspect you have only, thus far, written programs that consist of a single CPP file.

If you want a header-only library, global variables and functions must be marked `inline`.  But you need to learn how to make a project that consists of multiple CPP files linked together, and how to use libraries.  Libraries can include third-party code, not just reusable components of your own, so it's something you really need to learn!

As for the specific code...

```
namespace COLORS {
        #define CLASSIC (-1) //WORD

        #define INVISIBLEBLACK 0

        #define BLUE 1
        #define GREEN 2
        #define LIGHTBLUE 3
        #define RED 4
        #define PURPLE 5
        #define YELLOW 6
        #define WHITE 7
        #define GREY 8
        #define LIGHTBLUE 9
        #define LIGHTGREEN 10
        #define CYAN 11
        #define LIGHTRED 12
        #define PINK 13
        #define LIGHTYELLOW 14
        #define WHITE2 15
    }
    using namespace COLORS;
```

The `namespace` doesn't do anything since the `#define` does not respect namespaces at all.  It is one of the top issues that you should not use `#define` anyway, so change this to an enumerated type — a classic style `enum` will still let you use the enumeration names where an `int` is expected, if that is your intended use.

Also, defining a namespace and then immediately `using` it is a feature that's automated by using `inline`.  (This is a different use of the same keyword mentioned above).

`#ifdef _WIN32`
Well, you are including "Windows.h" at the top, so you are already committed to Windows for this file.

```
//Returns string converted to LPSTR
    LPSTR StrToLPSTR(string s) {
        return const_cast <char*> (s.c_str());
    }
```

Major bug!  You are passing `s` *by value*, so `s.c_str()` will return a pointer to the buffer (or internal SSO area) that is *destroyed* when `s` goes out of scope, which is when the function returns.

You also should not be casting away the const.  Don't do this.  If you need a non-const nul-terminated C-style string, make sure you produce one that can be written to.

```
//Returns true if given char is number
    bool isCharNumber(char c) {
        return isdigit(c);
    }
```

Why???  This adds nothing over the standard function.  If you are intentionally taking care of the legacy `int` parameter issue, overload it using the **same name**.

```
//Deleting chars from first parameter that are in second.
    string DeleteAllChars(string s, string chars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++)
            s = DeleteAllChars(s, chars[i]);
        return s;
    }
```

You are passing the second parameter, `chars`, *by value* which is not appropriate.  Do you understand that this deep-copies the entire string?  If it will not be modified, what is the point of that?
It's very inefficient, deleting all occurrences of one character at a time, recopying the whole string object each time.
Use `std::remove_if` followed by `erase` (look up "delete/erase idiom").  **In general**, become familiar with the standard library and other libraries in your project.

```
//Returns a chracter table length.
    int CharacterTableLength() {
        //return int(char(0) - 1);
        char a = 'a' + 1;
        int counter = 1;
        while (a != 'a') {
            a++;
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

I don't even understand what this is supposed to do.  It doesn't take any parameters or refer to any global names, so what "chracter[sic] table" are you talking about?  It looks like it increments a `char` value until it wraps around, thus (if that were legal) telling you the number of possible values in a `char`.  If you don't want to just assume it's 256, use `numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()+1`.
But this code is actually exhibiting *Undefined Behavior* as you are not allowed to wrap-around a signed number.  The optimizer will look at the condition in your `while` loop and say "Oh, that's always false" and replace your code with an infinite loop, or delete it altogether.

> function that should return number of all symbols installed on the computer. For example, if on computer installed 3 languages, this function should return number of special and 3 languages symbols.

No, it increments a `char` which has nothing to do with what languages are installed, or which of those `char` values has a legal code point assigned to it.  It just works as a small (8 bit) integer, having nothing to do with the Locale or selected font or anything.

```
template <typename T>
    string NumberToString(T pNumber) {
        ostringstream oOStrStream;
        oOStrStream << pNumber;
        return oOStrStream.str();
    }
```

That is just a slow re-implementation of [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).  What's wrong with `to_string`?

```
//Returns true if element is part of array.
    template <class element, class container>
    bool PartOfArray(element elem, container array, int arraySize=0) {
        if (!arraySize) arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            if (elem == array[i])
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Ugh, don't use the old C `sizeof` trick to determine array sizes.  It's brittle and will give the wrong answer if you end up giving it a parameter that's already decayed into a pointer.

Don't use the legacy `for` loop with index numbers when the range-based `for` will do.

But, your code, even though `container` is templated, only works with bare C style arrays, not with containers in general.  And you are just reproducing existing standard functions anyway!

Just see if `std::count` is non-zero, or (more efficient since it can quit when it finds the first match) if `std::find` returns something other than the `end`.

Even writing out the logic (not using library function) with the previous tips would make it work with *any* container, such as `vector`, not just plain C arrays:

```
    template <typename element, typename container>
    bool PartOfArray(element elem, container array) {
        for (const auto& val : array)
            if (elem == elem) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Oh, I noticed you are passing `container array` *by value*.  If you actually called this with an array, it will have decayed to a pointer in the parameter!  So remember what I said about the `sizeof` trick being easy to silently get wrong?   `sizeof (array)` actually returns the size of a single pointer, nothing to do with the original array.

Look at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/94n4s5z5K):
If the optional 3rd parameter is not given, it is replace with the value `2` even though the array size is `2089`.  You can see why in the signature reported in the assembly view: `int, int*, int`.  See, the "array" is actually passed as a pointer to the first element.

**Had you tested your code, you would have noticed that it did not work at all**.

Comment: That isn't really a "legacy `int` parameter issue". Allowed arguments are all values of type `unsigned char` and `EOF`. Anything else is UB.

Comment: `sizeof container` is a compilation-error. `sizeof (container)` would be the same as `sizeof array`, and pretty useless if the argument passed is a native array.

Comment: @Deduplicator corrected.  Interesting that the template argument deduction gives the decayed type when the parameter is `container x` (with no `&`).  I'll have to review the rules for that.   By "legacy 'int' parameter" I meant that the function, inherited from C (thus "Legacy"), takes an `int` and doesn't work with normal `char` which is signed.  Using it correctly requires casting, or better yet making your own wrapper that takes `char`.  Using it correctly requires extra work, thus it's an "issue".

Comment: That is not in any way surprising. A function cannot have an argument of type array. If it looks like it does, that really is a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your `s2ws()` function is a recursive function with no base condition. Presumably, it's from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode)? Notice where the closing braces are placed. It's also invoking undefined behavior because it's returning a pointer to memory that will be deallocated once the function returns.
   Same with `StrToLPSTR()` and `NumberToString()` functions.

---

2. `#define`s are not bound by namespace. The `COLORS` namespace is literally empty at the time of compilation. The compiler isn't throwing a compile error because you've used `using namespace COLORS;`.

---

3. As mentioned above, use `constexpr` to define constants.

---

4. If you're using C++17, you used should `std::filesystem` instead of relying on specific OS calls. It has the benefit of being portable.

---

5. If you're using C++17, you should generally use `std::string_view` instead of `const std::string&`.

---

6. You can use `std::to_string` instead of using `std::stringstream` in the `NumberToString()` function.

Right now, the function can accept any type. The constrain them to numeric types, you can use `static_assert` to do a compile time check. Using the `type_traits` library, you can do

`static_assert(is_integral_v<T> && is_floating_point_v<T>, "only numeric types allowed"!);`

This will now throw an error if you pass in any other type other than numeric types.

---

7. `PartOfArray` contains a bug. What if someone passes a C-style array and doesn't pass the size?

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
bool inArray = PartOfArray(3, arr);
std::cout << std::boolalpha << inArray; // prints false;
```

---

8. Use `<chrono>` library instead of `<time.h>`. Use `<random>` library instead of `rand()`

---

9. The `PlusPlus()` method invokes undefined behavior because of an out-of-bounds memory access. Hint: what happens when `a=0` and `res=""`?

---

10. Some are the comments are redundant. Code should be as self-documenting as possible. `Returns true if function returns 0` doesn't add anything that I can't figure out by looking at the code.

---